# On Duplicate Key Update is creating a new row instead of updating

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a datatable called buildTracker. A php form Posts the data for submission to create new ID/rows. That much works great. A second form pulls up existing rows for edit -

However instead of updating the existing row, it creates a new row and new key (ID)

How can I get the key to update without creating a new row?

```
$enteredBy    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['enteredBy']);
   $query   = "INSERT into buildtracker (EnteredBy)
    VALUES('" . $enteredBy . "')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE EnteredBy='" . $enteredBy . "'";

$success = $conn->query($query);
```

Where am I going wrong with the updating?

Datatable rows include ID (key) and EnteredBy (text)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Have you defined any unique index for your table ?

Comment: and any errors with `mysqli_error($conn)` ?

Comment: You're only specifying one column in the insert, and I doubt that that is the key that you don't want to duplicate. You need to specify the potentially duplicated key[s] in the insert statement in order for `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to work.

Comment: There's 15 columns in the statement - I took them out for the sake of length.     @Sammitch so you're saying to delcare the ID as key in the statement?

Comment: If you don't declare the key then how do you suppose mysql is going to know that the key is a duplicate?

Comment: Assumed since the Key was set on the data table it would not need to be declared in the statement

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it, your table, buildTracker, has a auto-incremented key field on it.  If you do a describe on the table, my guess is that that's what it would show.  The fact you are inserting a date means that the auto-increment will fire and you will never create a duplicate.  If you have EnteredBy as the primary key, it should ALWAYS update where that $enteredBy exists.

Comment: An auto incrementing ID is my Primary key. I'm not passing that data through my POST messages

Comment: Exactly.  By doing an insert of a value which is NOT the primary key, you are guaranteed to never update, always insert.  Why?  Because the auto-increment will fire at the insert statement and never fire an update.  To accomplish what you want, you have to update the row based on the key, you can't use an insert on dupe update for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an `update`, I would guess.  The update would look like:

```
UPDATE buildtracker 
    SET EnteredBy = ?
    WHERE <some column> = ?;
```

`<some column> = ?` would identify this row to be updated.  The only reason you would not have this is if the table contained only one row.

The use of `?` is to indicate that you should be using parameters.  You should not be munging query strings with input values; you should use parameters to avoid unexpected syntax errors and sql injection vulnerabilities.